# Using a loop to add lines to a Histogram in R

Tags: r, loops, histogram

I need to use `abline()` to add a yellow dashed vertical line at each of the ten most frequent values observed in a histogram. I think the best way to do this would be with a loop, but when I tried it didn't work. What's the best way to do this without writing 10 repetitive lines of code?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: And please read [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the return from `hist`,  it has all of the information that you need to compute this.  `counts` will let you pick the ten tallest bars. The yellow lines were nearly invisible, so I am plotting them in red, but you can just change the color to yellow if you want.

```
set.seed(2017)
Samp = sample(30, 1000, replace=TRUE)
HSamp = hist(Samp, breaks=30)
ToMark = tail(order(HSamp$counts), 10)
abline(v=ToMark+0.5, lty=2, col="red")
```

[image: Lined histogram]